# How to keep div in the center of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, viewport

I am creating a feedback system for one of my projects. My target device is iPad. Basically what happens is a div called into the page via ajax and it is supposed to overlay the content underneath. I have that part working.

What I want to do is have the div locked to the middle of the view-port. I have tried `position:fixed` on my element which works, except it will lock into the wrong position. It seems to be centering itself to the initial position of the viewport. If I scroll down to the bottom of a longer page and call my feedback window, it will still be near the top.

### Ajax Page (this runs when the page is called)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".popup").css({
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    marginLeft: -$(".popup").width() / 2,
    marginTop: -$(".popup").height() / 2
  });
});
```

If I can find the top of the viewport I think I'd be able to get this working right.

I've looked into: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Any help, advice or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed positioning is applied relative to the top-left corner of the window, *regardless of how far down you're scrolled* (which I assume is what you want).

So:

```
.popup {
   position:fixed;
   top:20px;
   left:40px;
   right:40px;
}
```

Will, first of all, put your popup 20px from the address bar (meaning, even if you scrolled to the bottom).

Next, setting both `left` AND `right` will "stretch" the fixed element to start and end 40px  (or whatever you give it) from both sides of the window. That's a convenient way of centering this popup div.

If your popup needs to be a fixed size – not stretched based on the width of the window – you could set both the left and right (to zero probably) and then inside this div, have another div with `margin:0 auto`, which will center that inner div within the fixed outer div.

P.S.
Just as you can set both `left` and `right`, you can also set both `top` and `bottom`, which will have corresponding results. However, if you need a fixed height, you won't be able to vertically center it using the `margin:auto` trick.

Comment: Thank you! I used these concepts and got something working! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the case, but If `$(".popup")` it's initially hidden by `display:none`, then it's width and height will be zero on page load.